# Porque se declara PUBLIC e xmlns usando site w3.org?

Tags: html, html5

Sempre tive essa dúvida, porque a maioria dos sites declaram argumentos `PUBLIC` na tag `!DOCTYPE` e `xmlns` na tag `html` e porque sempre os valores desses argumentos são links do *w3.org*? Procurei diversas vezes mas não encontrei nada, deve ter errado o termo de busca.

**Exemplo:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: Sobre o XMLNS -> http://www.maujor.com/w3c/xhtml10_2ed.html#ref-xmlns

Comment: Bom, se você tiver paciência pra ler (e manjar de inglês): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255470/what-are-the-different-doctypes-in-html-and-what-do-they-mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse exemplo de código está em XHTML, um padrão que tenta unificar HTML com XML. Ambas as linguagens são bastante semelhantes, mas há algumas diferenças cruciais, por isso a necessidade de se especificar um `DOCTYPE`.

O [Doctype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration) é uma declaração que associa o documento corrente com um [DTD](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Tipo_de_Documento) (*"document type definition"*), este responsável por definir qual a sintaxe exata utilizada (XML ou SGML, da qual HTML é um dialeto), quais elementos são permitidos, quais atributos, etc. A sintaxe geral dessa declaração é:

```
<!DOCTYPE root-element PUBLIC "FPI" ["URI"] [ 
<!-- internal subset declarations -->
]>
```

ou:

```
<!DOCTYPE root-element SYSTEM "URI" [ 
<!-- internal subset declarations -->
]>
```

No seu exemplo, o elemento raiz é o `html` (a tag principal do documento), o tipo é público (pois a especificação HTML é aberta ao público), o primeiro valor entre aspas é um identificador único para aquele DTD, e o segundo valor é a URI pública do documento que o descreve.

No caso, trata-se de um XHTML. Se fosse HTML 4 modo estrito, por exemplo, seria:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

No caso do HTML5, a sintaxe permite omitir a declaração de um DTD, dizendo somente que "o documento é HTML5" e mais nada:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Já o `xmlns` nada mais é que um [*namespace* XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) - como um documento XHTML é um tipo de XML, ele pode possuir um *namespace* que determina o significado de cada um dos elementos nesse documento. Se você quisesse embutir um outro tipo de documento dentro do XHTML, por exemplo SVG ou MathML, e esses documentos tivessem elementos com o mesmo nome dos elementos XHTML, poderia entrar em conflito. O uso de *namespaces* ajuda nesse sentido, permitindo que você prefixe os elementos "estrangeiros" com um identificador dizendo que eles são elementos de um tipo diferente de documento, com seu próprio *namespace*. Exemplo:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>A Math Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>The following is MathML markup:</p>
    <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
      <apply> <log/>
        <logbase>
          <cn> 3 </cn>
        </logbase>
        <ci> x </ci>
      </apply>
    </math>
  </body>
</html>
```

<sup>[Fonte](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/normative.html#well-formed)</sup>

Nesse exemplo acima, todos os elementos dentro de `math` são considerados elementos do MathML, e não do XHTML, para fins de validação. Nesse caso não foram necessários prefixos (pois os elementos não se misturaram), mas em outros casos eles poderiam ser necessários:

```
<!-- initially, the default namespace is "books" -->
<book xmlns='urn:loc.gov:books'
      xmlns:isbn='urn:ISBN:0-395-36341-6' xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <title>Cheaper by the Dozen</title>
  <isbn:number>1568491379</isbn:number>
```

No trecho acima, o elemento `title` pertence ao *namespace* padrão do documento, enquanto o elemento `number` pertence a outro *namespace*.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que você esteja olhando para páginas HTML4.
As páginas HTML5 já mudaram de padrão.

A ideia do HTML4 era manter uma alta compatibilidade com o formato XML. Neste formato, as coisas podem ser bem restritas, com o objetivo de você poder validar contra um arquivo que contém as regras do que pode existir ou não no XML. Um exemplo disso é as NF-e brasileira. Os campos são marcados com um XMLNS (XML Name Space) que indica que `tipo` (ou `type`) deve contar cada 1, exemplo: string, data, ou até mesmo algum tipo de marcação. Estes são arquivos XSDs (XML Schema).

O HTML4 tinha esta ideia, de que tudo seria exatamente muito definido e que poderia usar validadores para verificar se a página HTML tinha algum erro.

Mas a coisa evoluiu. Percebeu-se a importância de utilizar mais marcações para identificar seções (`<footer>` , `<header>`, `<section>`, etc) e também de adicionar atributos não padrão (aqueles que estão nos dentro de divs e outros, como por exemplo `<div data-info="X">`) que são acrescentados dinamicamente por jquery, angularjs, d3 e outras bibliotecas com o intuito de tornar o HTML mais rico sem "quebrá-lo". Não faz sentido validar isso contra um namespace. Então a coisa mudou.

E uma última coisa. Como quem especificava qual era o HTML "Puro" é o W3C, eles é que possuíam sempre os XSDs mais novos e atualizados de acordo com as versões dos padrões. Portanto sempre você precisava apontar pra eles.

Não sei se é esta sua curiosidade, mas espero que ajude nas suas pesquisas.

Comment: Concordo com o que escreveu, mas note que HTML4 é diferente de XHTML. Essas declarações no exemplo do AP referem-se ao XHTML e não o HTML seja em que versão for. Além disso, o HTML5 não abandonou essa lógica de validação, etc, ele simplesmente deixou *implícito* certas coisas se você não declará-las explicitamente. (ou seja, ainda dá sim pra validar HTML5 contra um namespace)